# dnsmasq and lxc with wildcard DNS subdomains

Tags: lxc, dnsmasq

I'm using LXC to create a new containers. All of them are using dnsmasq with DHCP to get their IP address and to have local DNS server. I setup a domain .lxc in dnsmasq. So every container will get DNS address .lxc. But I didn't found any solution how to support subdomains anything..lxc.

I can do that only manually by adding a line to the dnsmasq config

```
address=/.server.mydomain.com/192.168.0.3
```

is there any automatic way so I don't need to do that for every new container and restart the dhcp server?